# Z axis won't line up perpendicular to object's face/vertex when snapping to vertex, how do I correct this?

Tags: vertices, snapping

What I want it to do is on the right (simpler octahedron object) but for some reason, it behaves terribly for the other complex object on the left.

Each of the 8 faces behaves differently but to some degree they are all tilted slightly instead of being projecting perfectly away.

https://youtu.be/V75OqiEISb0

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your objects: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Here is the file:

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=G2WoZqNB" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/G2WoZqNB/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Snap* panel, choose *Face Project*, apply the *Scale* of the big object, and it works:

[image]

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work for me. When you say 'apply the Scale of the big object' what do you mean exactly? The octahedral obj or the socket obj?

Comment: Select the octahedral object and Ctrl A > Apply Scale

Comment: That did it, Thanks you!